# Qt static build with -target xp has MF.dll dependency

Tags: qt, windows-xp, qmediaplayer

I ran ./configure with -static -static-runtime -target xp. Unfortuantely my application does not run when I use QMediaPlayer on Windows XP. There is a missing reference to MF.dll which aborts the program start with a critical error message.

Pretty much this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42460

Does anyone has figured out how to clean the reference to MF.dll? My guess was -no-wmf-backend, but the person who reported the bug said it's not enough. Before I recompile another 8 hours, I would like to have some clarification, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config.tests` before building Qt and running configure, there is a file called evr. Let it fail to avoid MF.dll dependency on Windows XP. QMediaPlayer will just work fine then.